# How to animate a canvas in real time

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to change the fill colour of each zone(segment) of the decagon depending on each number is the list L.

Currently it only displays the canvas at the end and using the last number in the list L.

The idea is each time it reads a number from the list L it updates the canvas, fills that zone and changes the last filled zone back to white

The zones ('zn') are from 0-5, 0 Being the inside decagon and 1-5 the outside. and a combination of zones formatted 1_2, 2_3, 3_4, 4_5 and 5_1

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()
cWidth = 800
cHeight = 650
canvas = Canvas(root, width=cWidth, height=cHeight)
canvas.pack()

zn1 = canvas.create_polygon(257, 635, 319, 445, 269, 409, 107, 526,outline='blue',fill='white',tag='z1',)
zn12 = canvas.create_polygon(107, 526, 269, 409, 250, 350, 50, 350,outline='black',fill='white', tag='z1_2')
zn2 = canvas.create_polygon(50, 350, 250, 350, 269, 291, 107, 174,outline='purple',fill='white', tag='z2')
zn23 = canvas.create_polygon(107, 174, 269, 291, 319, 255, 257, 65,outline='black',fill='white', tag='z2_3')
zn3 = canvas.create_polygon(257, 65, 443, 65, 381, 255, 319, 255,outline='orange',fill='white', tag='z3')
zn34 = canvas.create_polygon(443, 65, 381, 255, 431, 291, 593, 174,outline='black',fill='white', tag='z3_4')
zn4 = canvas.create_polygon(593, 174, 431, 291, 450, 350, 650, 350,outline='cyan',fill='white', tag='z4')
zn45 = canvas.create_polygon(650, 350, 450, 350, 431, 409, 593, 526,outline='black',fill='white', tag='z4_5')
zn5 = canvas.create_polygon(593, 526, 431, 409, 381, 445, 443, 635,outline='green',fill='white', tag='z5')
zn51 = canvas.create_polygon(443, 635, 381, 445, 319, 445, 257, 635,outline='black',fill='white', tag='z5_1')
zn0 = canvas.create_polygon(381, 255, 319, 255, 269, 291, 250, 350, 269, 409, 319, 445, 381, 445, 431, 409, 450, 350,
                            431, 291,outline='black',fill='white', tag='z0')

L= ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5',
        '5', '5', '1_5', '1_5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1_5', '5', '1',
        '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1_2', '2', '1_2', '0_1', '0_1', '0_1', '0_1', '1', '1',
        '0_1', '0', '0_1_2', '1_2', '1', '1_2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2_3',
        '2_3', '0_2_3', '0_2', '0_2', '0_2', '2', '2', '2', '2_3', '3', '2_3', '2', '2_3', '2_3_4', '3_4', '3', '3',
        '3_4', '3_4', '2_3_4', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3',
        '3', '4', '3', '3', '3_4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '3_4', '4', '4', '0_3_4', '3_4', '3', '3', '3', '3', '0', '4',
        '0_4', '4', '4', '5', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4_5', '4_5', '4_5', '4_5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '0_5',
        '0_5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5',
        '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5',
        '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '1_5', '5', '5', '5', '1',
        '1_5', '0_5', '0', '0', '0', '0_1_5', '0_5', '0_5', '0_1', '0_1', '0', '1', '1_2', '0_2', '0_1', '0_1', '0_1',
        '2', '1_2', '1', '0_1_2', '0_1_2', '0_1_2', '1_3', '3', '0', '0_2', '2', '2', '0', '0_2', '2', '2', '0_3',
        '0_3', '0_3', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '3_4', '0_3_4', '0_3_4', '0', '0', '4', '5', '5', '0', '4_5', '4_5',
        '4_5', '4', '4', '4', '4', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5',
        '5', '5', '1']

def resetMap():
    canvas.itemconfig(zn0, fill='white')
    canvas.itemconfig(zn1, fill='white')
    canvas.itemconfig(zn12, fill='white')
    canvas.itemconfig(zn2, fill='white')
    canvas.itemconfig(zn23, fill='white')
    canvas.itemconfig(zn3, fill='white')
    canvas.itemconfig(zn34, fill='white')
    canvas.itemconfig(zn4, fill='white')
    canvas.itemconfig(zn45, fill='white')
    canvas.itemconfig(zn5, fill='white')
    canvas.itemconfig(zn51, fill='white')

def update(tkn):
    if len(tkn) == 1:
        if '0' in tkn:
            canvas.itemconfig(zn0, fill='red')
        elif '1' in tkn:
            canvas.itemconfig(zn1, fill='red')
        elif '2' in tkn:
            canvas.itemconfig(zn2, fill='red')
        elif '3' in tkn:
            canvas.itemconfig(zn3, fill='red')
        elif '4' in tkn:
            canvas.itemconfig(zn4, fill='red')
        elif '5' in tkn:
            canvas.itemconfig(zn5, fill='red')
    else:
        # run combination
        if '0' in tkn:
            canvas.itemconfig(zn0, fill='red')
        elif '1' in tkn and '2' in tkn:
            canvas.itemconfig(zn12, fill='red')
        elif '2' in tkn and '3' in tkn:
            canvas.itemconfig(zn23, fill='red')
        elif '3' in tkn and '4' in tkn:
            canvas.itemconfig(zn34, fill='red')
        elif '4' in tkn and '5' in tkn:
            canvas.itemconfig(zn45, fill='red')
        elif '5' in tkn and '1' in tkn:
            canvas.itemconfig(zn51, fill='red')

def task():
    for i in L:
        print(i)
        resetMap()
        tkn = i.split('_')
        update(tkn)
        time.sleep(0.1)

task()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe your function used in a incorrect way.You could call `.after` instead of use `time.sleep()`.And don't use a for loop in the function,I revise your `task()` function:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()
cWidth = 800
cHeight = 650
canvas = Canvas(root, width=cWidth, height=cHeight)
canvas.pack()

zn1 = canvas.create_polygon(257, 635, 319, 445, 269, 409, 107, 526,outline='blue',fill='white',tag='z1',)
zn12 = canvas.create_polygon(107, 526, 269, 409, 250, 350, 50, 350,outline='black',fill='white', tag='z1_2')
zn2 = canvas.create_polygon(50, 350, 250, 350, 269, 291, 107, 174,outline='purple',fill='white', tag='z2')
zn23 = canvas.create_polygon(107, 174, 269, 291, 319, 255, 257, 65,outline='black',fill='white', tag='z2_3')
zn3 = canvas.create_polygon(257, 65, 443, 65, 381, 255, 319, 255,outline='orange',fill='white', tag='z3')
zn34 = canvas.create_polygon(443, 65, 381, 255, 431, 291, 593, 174,outline='black',fill='white', tag='z3_4')
zn4 = canvas.create_polygon(593, 174, 431, 291, 450, 350, 650, 350,outline='cyan',fill='white', tag='z4')
zn45 = canvas.create_polygon(650, 350, 450, 350, 431, 409, 593, 526,outline='black',fill='white', tag='z4_5')
zn5 = canvas.create_polygon(593, 526, 431, 409, 381, 445, 443, 635,outline='green',fill='white', tag='z5')
zn51 = canvas.create_polygon(443, 635, 381, 445, 319, 445, 257, 635,outline='black',fill='white', tag='z5_1')
zn0 = canvas.create_polygon(381, 255, 319, 255, 269, 291, 250, 350, 269, 409, 319, 445, 381, 445, 431, 409, 450, 350,
                            431, 291,outline='black',fill='white', tag='z0')

L= ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5',
        '5', '5', '1_5', '1_5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1_5', '5', '1',
        '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1_2', '2', '1_2', '0_1', '0_1', '0_1', '0_1', '1', '1',
        '0_1', '0', '0_1_2', '1_2', '1', '1_2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2_3',
        '2_3', '0_2_3', '0_2', '0_2', '0_2', '2', '2', '2', '2_3', '3', '2_3', '2', '2_3', '2_3_4', '3_4', '3', '3',
        '3_4', '3_4', '2_3_4', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3',
        '3', '4', '3', '3', '3_4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '3_4', '4', '4', '0_3_4', '3_4', '3', '3', '3', '3', '0', '4',
        '0_4', '4', '4', '5', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4_5', '4_5', '4_5', '4_5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '0_5',
        '0_5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5',
        '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5',
        '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '1_5', '5', '5', '5', '1',
        '1_5', '0_5', '0', '0', '0', '0_1_5', '0_5', '0_5', '0_1', '0_1', '0', '1', '1_2', '0_2', '0_1', '0_1', '0_1',
        '2', '1_2', '1', '0_1_2', '0_1_2', '0_1_2', '1_3', '3', '0', '0_2', '2', '2', '0', '0_2', '2', '2', '0_3',
        '0_3', '0_3', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '3_4', '0_3_4', '0_3_4', '0', '0', '4', '5', '5', '0', '4_5', '4_5',
        '4_5', '4', '4', '4', '4', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5',
        '5', '5', '1']

def resetMap():
    canvas.itemconfig(zn0, fill='white')
    canvas.itemconfig(zn1, fill='white')
    canvas.itemconfig(zn12, fill='white')
    canvas.itemconfig(zn2, fill='white')
    canvas.itemconfig(zn23, fill='white')
    canvas.itemconfig(zn3, fill='white')
    canvas.itemconfig(zn34, fill='white')
    canvas.itemconfig(zn4, fill='white')
    canvas.itemconfig(zn45, fill='white')
    canvas.itemconfig(zn5, fill='white')
    canvas.itemconfig(zn51, fill='white')

def update(tkn):
    if len(tkn) == 1:
        if '0' in tkn:
            canvas.itemconfig(zn0, fill='red')
        elif '1' in tkn:
            canvas.itemconfig(zn1, fill='red')
        elif '2' in tkn:
            canvas.itemconfig(zn2, fill='red')
        elif '3' in tkn:
            canvas.itemconfig(zn3, fill='red')
        elif '4' in tkn:
            canvas.itemconfig(zn4, fill='red')
        elif '5' in tkn:
            canvas.itemconfig(zn5, fill='red')
    else:
        # run combination
        if '0' in tkn:
            canvas.itemconfig(zn0, fill='red')
        elif '1' in tkn and '2' in tkn:
            canvas.itemconfig(zn12, fill='red')
        elif '2' in tkn and '3' in tkn:
            canvas.itemconfig(zn23, fill='red')
        elif '3' in tkn and '4' in tkn:
            canvas.itemconfig(zn34, fill='red')
        elif '4' in tkn and '5' in tkn:
            canvas.itemconfig(zn45, fill='red')
        elif '5' in tkn and '1' in tkn:
            canvas.itemconfig(zn51, fill='red')

index = 0

def task(i):
    if i == len(L): # check whether the index larger than the length of the list.
        return
    resetMap()
    tkn = L[i].split('_')
    update(tkn)
    root.after(100,task,i+1) # call this function per 0.1 second

root.after(100,task,index) # call after function and pass a index argument
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: There's no need to call `root.update()` inside of `task`.